# ASP.NET CORE AND SSRS Parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I want to display in my report the users of our System, who printed the reports. SSRS does have Built-in Fields but it only shows the computer name and the user, not the one who is logged in to our system. I have the idea of parameters but I don't have the right program on how to do it.

Comment: Read about URL access and parameters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-parameter-reference?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks for this but I don't user report server.

Comment: SSRS and Power BI Report Server are the same  for Paginated Reports.

Comment: I mean I don't use report server.

Comment: SSRS works too.

Comment: Yes. I use SSRS. but I need the code on how to display the logged username from our system and show it in our ssrs report

Comment: So read about URL Access and parameters.